# Powershell Register WPF events

Tags: wpf, powershell, events

I'm trying to build a WPF gui where i have two radiobutton listboxes.
A button loads the radio buttons:

```
function mybuttonclick {
    $List = get-content "list.txt"
    foreach ($item in $list) {
        $tmpradio = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton
        $tmpradio.content = "$item"
        $tmpradio.groupname = "MyList"
        Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $tmpradio -EventName Checked -Action { write-host "test"}
        $MyListbox.AddChild($tmpradio)
    }
}
```

However i'm getting nothing back, is it a scope issue where the object gets deleted after exiting from the function?

Is there a solution to make so i can pick an action or another wheter the groupname is "MyList" or for example "MyOtherList"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like i will once more answer my own question..

It honestly is as simple as i tought it would...
Jim Moyle explained it, i adapted to my situation..

```
function mybuttonclick {
    $List = get-content "list.txt"
    foreach ($item in $list) {
        $tmpradio = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton
        $tmpradio.content = "$item"
        $tmpradio.groupname = "MyList"
        [System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler]$checkhandler = {write-host 'Test'}
        $tmpradio.AddHandler([System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton]::CheckedEvent, $checkhandler)
        $MyListbox.AddChild($tmpradio)
    }
}
```

To make it simple i just create my radio button as usual,
then i create a handler scriptblock, which is just code executed on x event triggered.

At last i add that handler to my radiobutton on the CheckedEvent.

I could find the event name by opening up a debugger, type down this:

```
[System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton]::
```

and then start tabbing for autocompletion

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6A9KuEM324